# matrix text style in action script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, motion

I am working in AS3, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a matrix effect (the moving green text lines in the movie) in action script. I have found a few examples online, but none of them seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great effect with source code:

http://www.bherholz.com/experiments/matrix/